# How to connect to a SQL Server database in a container or local from a other container

Tags: sql-server, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I created an ASP.NET Core Web App project from samples with individual user authentication and docker support.

Then using Powershell, I created a container where the SQL Server is running with:

```
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Test1234" -p 1433:1433 --name webappdb1 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest
```

I tested if I can connect to the SQL Server with SQL Server Management Studio:

- with localhost, SQL Server authentication, username, password (for testing if I can connect to local SQL Server)
- with localhost,1433, SQL Server authentication, username, password (for testing if I can connect to SQL server running inside the container container)

Both tests worked successfully.

In the ASP.NET Core Web project, I changed the connection string to connect to the local SQL Server in `appsettings.json`:

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=WebApp5;User ID=SA;Password=Test1234;Current Language=German;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

and

```
"Data Source=localhost,1433;Initial Catalog=WebApp5;User ID=SA;Password=Test1234;Current Language=German;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

I can run the application within Docker from VS. When I want register a new account from the sample project I get the following error with both connections strings:

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I do not have a docker-compose file. The Dockerfile is unchanged.
Docker ps:

```
7ac6ef664be0   webapplication5:dev                          "tail -f
/dev/null"      39 minutes ago   Up 38 minutes  
0.0.0.0:49154->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49153->443/tcp   WebApplication5  
265175f4f125   mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest  
"/opt/mssql/bin/perm…"   43 minutes ago   Up 43 minutes  
0.0.0.0:1433->1433/tcp                          webappdb1
```

I tried already "0.0.0.0" as Data Source in the connection string.
I tried enabling tcp for local SQL Server (https://jack-vanlightly.com/blog/2017/9/24/how-to-connect-to-your-local-sql-server-from-inside-docker)

Comment: try host.docker.internal insteadof localhost in connectionstring.

Comment: It worked! It seems localhost and localhost:1433 is same SQL Server and it's the local (not the one in Container). But when I create a SQL Server in another Container on 1434 how can i connect to it from the WebApp Container?

Comment: Docker containers are essentially their own little Linux VMs so the localhost addresses `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `::1` refer to the container itself.

Comment: Consider orchestrating your containers inside a Docker Composition (docker-compose.yml), or at least in a Docker network (that's not the default bridge network) so that there are container-related DNS services available. Then you can use DNS lookups to reference other containers in the composition by name.