# Connect to local SQL Server database from a Windows container

Tags: sql-server, docker, testcontainers

I have a Windows docker image containing my application that needs to access to a database.

I'm writing some integration tests and I'm currently using the TestContainers framework.

The problem I'm facing is the application inside my container cannot reach the database installed on the host.

What I have in my test setup is:

```
_network = new NetworkBuilder()
  .WithName(_name)
  .Build();

_myContainer = new ContainerBuilder()
  .WithImage("myWindowsApplication:1.0.0.0")
  .WithExposedPort(1433)
  .WithNetwork(_network)
  .Build();

await _network.CreateAsync();
await _myContainer.StartAsync();
```

The Server I'm using to construct the connection string is `My-Computer\SQLEXPRESS`.

I've tried a couple of things:

- First I tried to use `Dotnet.TestContainers.Sql` but here the issue is that the image provided by the nuget package is based on Linux and this conflicts with my custom docker image which is instead based on Windows;
- Since most answers suggest to set the network to host when running the container, I've modified the network builder with this additional configuration

  ```
  .WithDriver(NetworkDriver.Host)
  ```

  but in this case, I also got an exception when starting the container:

  > Docker.DotNet.DockerApiException : Docker API responded with status code=NotFound, response={"message":"could not find plugin host in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found"}
- I also tried, just for desperation, to change the SQL Server name like this `(host.docker.internal)\SQLEXPRESS` because I read that here on Stackoverflow ([How to connect to a SQL Server database in a container or local from a other container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73624512/how-to-connect-to-a-sql-server-database-in-a-container-or-local-from-a-other-con)) but also this try was a failure.

Does anyone have a suggestion to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Did you try `host.docker.internal\SQLEXPRESS` ? The host is visible to containers as `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I tried that as well but nothing :(

Comment: Why does the application container have `.WithExposedPort(1433)`? Is it also pretending to be an SQL Server instance? Exposed ports are meant for ports that an application is listening on for incoming connections.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning no it was a mistake then... the sql database is only on the host machine.

Comment: Ok, well there could be two things going on here: 1) For most versions of SQL Server Express it does not have the TCP/IP server protocol enabled by default, so have you checked in SQL Server (Version) Configuration Manager that the EXPRESS instance's TCP/IP protocol is enabled? 2) Using instance names in connection strings (the `\SQLEXPRESS` portion) requires the SQL Browser service - this is what accepts SSRP requests to resolve the instance name to a TCP/IP port number that it's actually listening on. Is the SQL Browser service running? Have you restarted it since last configuring Express?

Comment: Actually, a third thing comes to mind: Even when Express has the TCP/IP protocol enabled it often only listens on the localhost address. Inside SQL Server (Version) Configuration Manager, when enabling the TCP/IP server protocol, have you also checked its configuration to see which IP addresses it is enabled for and listening on? (It will need more than localhost to be reachable from containers.)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for the support. Tcp-ip protocol were actually disabled and I've enabled now. Also the SQL Browser Service was disabled and now it's running. I restarted the Sql server service but still have the connection issue